# Can Spring MVC deserialize JSON which can be object or array?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have controller receiving JSON in request body, which can be object or array of objects. For example:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Nick",
  "surname" : "Cave"
}
```

and

```
[
 {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Nick",
   "surname" : "Cave"
 },
 {
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "Jack",
   "surname" : "White"
 }
]
```

**Is there any way to force Spring to deserialize JSON to object in the similar way to object alone?**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postController(@RequestBody User user, ...) {
   ...
}
```

If not, what is the elegant way of parsing and validating those kind of messages?

Comment: take a look here : https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/

Comment: or using HttpMessageConverter : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody-demystified.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So 1) add to maven :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

2)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
  logger.debug(person.toString());
  return new JsonResponse("OK","");
}
```